# Bind event with form in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, forms, dom, dom-events

I am creating `form` using JavaScript. Like below

```
var form = document.createElement('form');
form.action = 'abc.com';
form.noValidate = true;
form.id = 'myForm';
form.onsubmit = 'return validateMyForm();';
```

I am trying to add validator that checks required fields before submit `form`. So I follow [JavaScript to stop form submission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8664486/javascript-to-stop-form-submission). But it didn't attach event to the `form`. How can I achieve this in JavaScript ?

*No JQuery please.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to assign a **function** to `onsubmit`, not a string:

```
form.onsubmit = validateMyForm;
```

---

Don't confuse *DOM properties* with *HTML attributes*. Writing something like

```
<form onsubmit="return foo();">
```

would be (roughly) equivalent to

```
form.onsubmit = function(event) {
    return foo();
};
```

when working with the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

You can't put a function into a string.

```
form.onsubmit = function() {
  var valid = true;

  // TODO: form validation

  // Not valid, return false
  if(!valid) {
    alert('Please correct the following errors:');
    return false;
  }

  // valid, do nothing.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use the `required` attribute of HTML5 on your `input` like so:

```
<input type="text" name="lastname" required>
```

This will cause html5 to validate the fields before submitting.
There are several other attributes that may be used for validation as well depending on the type of data you want to validate.

No need to use javascript for the validation.